# Distribute the app to client to get it resigned and pushed to appstore

Tags: ios, app-store, archive, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

I am planning to send an **xarchive** file which was created using **development provisioning profile and development certificate** to **client** and **client can resign it using their App Store certificates and provisioning profile**.

Some people warned me not do it because as it will give **development build so debugger informations** will be part of it and its debug build and development certificates are not meant to do this.

**Distribution certificates are meant to do it atleast I have to sign it using ADhoc provisioning profile and distribution certificate** for making the **xarchive** and this xarchive can be used by client and they can re-sign it again and it should not be a problem

I am very much confused with it.

Someone kindly clarify.

*Sending an xarchive which is signed by dev signers to client to re-sign it using their App Store signer is risky or not* ?

Comment: Why they need resign it ?? no need to do it , is it B2B or B2C app?

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari - B2B

Comment: I don't understand they have to resign to publish in App Store using their account right